# Let $H \subset G$ be finite groups. Suppose that $H$ is a $p$-group and $p$ divides $[ G : H ]$. Prove that $p$ divides $[N_G(H) : H ]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

> Let $G$ be a finie group, and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $H$ is a $p$-group and $p$ divides $[ G : H ]$. Prove that $p$ divides $[N_G(H) : H ]$.

As this question arose from a chapter dealing with (left) $G$-actions, I am thinking that I would have to use either the conjugation action or translation action on a $G$-set, perhaps on $G/H$ by $x * aH = xaH$. I am thinking I would probably have t use the orbit decomposition theorem, together with the fact $H$ is a $p$-group. But I am not sure how to proceed. I was thinking of the conjugation action, but I didn't get anywhere - though I might have missed something.

Comment: Just a comment: You may have missed the equidimensional thereom, that is the dimensions of the nullspace and range add up to the total dimension of the algebra. That is that p does divide iff the image of G is in the range of H.

Comment: There should be a way to prove this question without such theorem, as my textbook dos not mention it.

Comment: One way of doing this is to note that $H$ is to use Sylow's theorems to show that $H$ is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$, and the containement is proper, so $p$ divides $|N_P(H):H|$ and hence also $|N_G(H):H|$.

Comment: Indeed you could choose a more special subgroup with an exclusive isomorphic property for a proof less obvious to the universe.

Comment: Let $H$ act on its own cosets by multiplication. Because it is a p-group, and $p$ divides $[G:H]$, the number of fixed cosets is divisible by $p$. But a coset is fixed precisely when it's contained in $N(H)$.

Comment: @Steve D, could you further elaborate on your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ act on its own left cosets in $G$, and let $F$ be the set of cosets fixed by this action (the fixed "points").  Then the results follows from:

- $|F|=[G:H]\pmod{p}$ (this is because $H$ is a $p$-group)
- The coset $xH$ is fixed by this action iff $xH\subset N_G(H)$

The first is true in more generality: a finite $p$-group $P$, acting on a finite set $S$.  Then $|\text{Fix}|=|S|\pmod{p}$. It can be proved using the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

The second follows because $hxH=xH$ is equivalent to $x^{-1}hx\in H$.